# Print 'hashtags' from JSON to CSV file using Python

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, hashtag

I'm a beginner using the following code:

```
f = open("singletweetwithtimezone.json", "r")
tweet_text = f.read()

import json

tweet_json = json.loads(tweet_text)

g = open("Singletweetcsvoutput.csv", "w")

g.write(tweet_json["created_at"]+"\t")
g.write(tweet_json["user"]["time_zone"]+"\t")
g.write(tweet_json["entities"]["hashtags"]["text"])

g.close()
f.close()
```

The writing works, except for the hashtags. I want it to write the text 'messi' in the CSV file, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, due to a lack of knowledge. I get the following error:

```
g.write(tweet_json["entities"]["hashtags"]["text"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". "
```

The JSON tree is shown in the image i've added:
[what the tree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZeZI.png)

Anyone who can help me out?

RAW JSON code:

```
{"created_at":"Sun Apr 23 21:04:13 +0000 2017","id":856252394233106432,"id_str":"856252394233106432","text":"RT @11FC_FR: Et \u00e0 la fin ... #Messi \n\ud83d\ude0d https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1628829458,"id_str":"1628829458","name":"LK20","screen_name":"KeevinGruny","location":null,"url":null,"description":"\u26bd\ufe0f\u26bd\ufe0f","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":903,"friends_count":209,"listed_count":39,"favourites_count":7328,"statuses_count":59480,"created_at":"Sun Jul 28 21:50:55 +0000 2013","utc_offset":10800,"time_zone":"Athens","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/854838667428466688\/jE52U_LU_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/854838667428466688\/jE52U_LU_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1628829458\/1492857072","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Apr 23 20:38:37 +0000 2017","id":856245950544838660,"id_str":"856245950544838660","text":"Et \u00e0 la fin ... #Messi \n\ud83d\ude0d https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","display_text_range":[0,25],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2617563403,"id_str":"2617563403","name":"11FootballClub","screen_name":"11FC_FR","location":"3, All\u00e9e Cassard - NANTES","url":"http:\/\/www.11footballclub.com","description":"11FootballClub est un concept store unique et une boutique en ligne soign\u00e9e. Actus foot, nouveaut\u00e9s produits, promos et jeux concours","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":49693,"friends_count":24561,"listed_count":54,"favourites_count":350,"statuses_count":1268,"created_at":"Fri Jul 11 15:21:20 +0000 2014","utc_offset":-25200,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"A16E1E","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/648580532322836480\/2lodFucd_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/648580532322836480\/2lodFucd_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2617563403\/1443468740","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":155,"favorite_count":92,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Messi","indices":[16,22]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":856245937915793408,"id_str":"856245937915793408","indices":[26,49],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/uiyTnJJiKd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/11FC_FR\/status\/856245950544838660\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":460,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":812,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1386,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":856245937915793408,"id_str":"856245937915793408","indices":[26,49],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/uiyTnJJiKd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/11FC_FR\/status\/856245950544838660\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":460,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":812,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1386,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Messi","indices":[29,35]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"11FC_FR","name":"11FootballClub","id":2617563403,"id_str":"2617563403","indices":[3,11]}],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":856245937915793408,"id_str":"856245937915793408","indices":[39,62],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/uiyTnJJiKd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/11FC_FR\/status\/856245950544838660\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":460,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":812,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1386,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":856245950544838660,"source_status_id_str":"856245950544838660","source_user_id":2617563403,"source_user_id_str":"2617563403"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":856245937915793408,"id_str":"856245937915793408","indices":[39,62],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C-H_JNnXkAApCFh.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/uiyTnJJiKd","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/uiyTnJJiKd","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/11FC_FR\/status\/856245950544838660\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":680,"h":460,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":812,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1386,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":856245950544838660,"source_status_id_str":"856245950544838660","source_user_id":2617563403,"source_user_id_str":"2617563403"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr","timestamp_ms":"1492981453842"}
```

Comment: check the updated answer and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Start by printing the type of each different node in the response. The error that you see is caused by the fact that you are trying to access everything in the response as it was the key of a dictionary. Thing is that hashtags, from the screenshot, could be an array, hence needs to be accessed as:

```
tweet_json['entities']['hashtags'][0]['text']
```

Hashtags contains an array, in this case the length of the array is 1 so you'd access with [0], but since the  length of these arrays is variable you should add a check for length and then do a loop a little like below. I like to use dictwriter from the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) even if for this is an over kill, it can be used to go through several tweets.

```
import csv
import json


with open('.../input.json','r') as inputfile:
    tweet= inputfile.read()

tweet_json = json.loads(tweet)

with open('.../output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['created_at', 'user', 'hashtags']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    #extract all info that you want to write
    created_at = tweet_json['created_at']
    #selecting the screen_name of the user rather than id
    user = tweet_json['user']['screen_name']
    hashtags = tweet_json['entities']['hashtags']
    #creating an empty string for the hashtags in the array
    hashes = list()
    for hashtag in hashtags:
        text = hashtag['text']
        #append to hashes listed_count
        hashes.append(text)
    #stringify the list and write to file (will be ugly)
    writer.writerow({"created_at":created_at, "user":user,"hashtags":str(hashes) })
```

Comment: Thanks, here's the raw code, added to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update! How would that make the full code look like, I can't get it to work yet :').

Comment: @MaroYKW check this out